# What are some good French educational shows for toddlers?

Tags: apprentissage, éducation, enfants

A more colloquial way of phrasing the question is, *Is there a French Ms Rachel?*

J'ai étudié le français au lycée et à l'université. Je l'ai appris en anglais, qui est ma seconde langue; l'espagnol est ma première. Je peux le lire et écrire assez bien, mais je dois beaucoup réfléchir et chercher les mots que je ne comprends pas, et vérifier mon orthographe à l'aide de correcteurs en ligne. Je le comprends aussi bien à l'oral, si on parle un peu lentement, mais le parler est le plus difficile pour moi. Parce que je n'ai pas eu l'opportunité de le parler beaucoup depuis des années, je voudrais donner à ma fille l'opportunité de l'apprendre d'une manière plus authentique que celle que je lui pourrais offrir.

I would love to introduce my young child to entertaining shows that teach her vocabulary, such as letters, numbers, colors, and cultural references.

I know this question can be broad, so here are some examples of what I'm looking for (but with a French speaker):

- [Ms Rachel](https://www.youtube.com/@msrachel) -->  Ms. Rachel uses techniques
  recommended by speech therapists and early childhood experts to help
  children learn important milestones and preschool skills
- [Bilingual Little Stars](https://www.youtube.com/@bilinguallittlestars) --> Ms. Alejandra focuses on teaching young children Spanish, English and American Sign Language (ASL)

The best channels I've found so far are [CocoMelon en Français](https://www.youtube.com/@CoComelonFrancais) and [BlabberBeasts](https://www.youtube.com/@BlabberBeasts), but my daughter doesn't seem to enjoy them as much as the videos with a real human speaking.
The other YouTube channels I've encountered with French speakers aren't as well produced or interesting (in my humble opinion).

Aside from YouTube, I do have several French/English books I read to her (although right now, she's more interested in turning the pages and looking at the pictures than in me reading the stories), and we listen to the CD from the book [Un-deux-trois Premières Comptines Françaises](https://www.little-linguist.co.uk/un-deux-trois-first-french-rhymes.html)

I appreciate your help!

Comment: This question is not really about one of the ["finer points of the French language"](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour). For questions about second-language acquisition and language teaching you can visit [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com), they have a [French](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french) tag.

Comment: TV5 Monde a une [section pour les jeunes enfants](https://enseigner.tv5monde.com/fiches-pedagogiques-fle/enfants?f%5B0%5D=publics%3A2224), peut-être y trouveras-tu des activités qui te conviendront.

Comment: Thank you for the great tips @None!
I'll follow up in [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/?newreg=0670e638de0d4035a723132d85f7b110)